# Actors implementation built on C++0x thread standard

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, actor, c++11

I'm a little disappointed to find that the `C++0x` concurrency standard doesn't seem to have any native support for a message-passing Actors model.

Is there any support for this that I am missing?  Maybe something in futures/promises?  Is there any strong community effort to build a *de facto* standard implementation on top of the `C++0x` threading standards?

Comment: I think there is one such thing already: Boost.MPI.

Comment: How can there be a community effort to build something for a standard that hasn't even been published yet?

Comment: @Nicol: on the assumption that what was ratified earlier this month is very similar to what has been published earlier in draft form; the same reason there are already books available about C++11 concurrency.

Comment: @R. Martinho: thanks, that looks useful, but it sounds like it is essentially a traditional MPI implementation designed for interprocess communication.  What I am asking for would be something like that but with the option to use lightweight threads instead of only heavier processes.

Comment: Hmm, I notice that Theron (http://theron.ashtonmason.net/index.php) is an Actors implementation designed to sit on top of pluggable threading models.  There is a wrapper for Boost threads already, and C++11 std::thread is supposed to be quite similar to Boost, so probably this will work.  Haven't actually tried using Theron yet, but will probably give it a whirl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently I have found two possible solutions: [Theron](http://www.theron-library.com/) and [libcppa](http://libcppa.blogspot.com/).  Both are based on Boost threads and so should be easily portable to C++11 threads.  Both are developed by individuals.

Mostly because I found it first, and because it has very nice documentation, I went ahead and tried `Theron` and it works quite nicely.  My test application was not especially Actors appropriate, and only needed as many Actors as hardware cores, but I got about 4.5x speedup with 6 threads on 6 cores and 6x speedup with 12 threads on 6 cores with hyperthreading.  Pretty good and it only took a few hours to get working and I didn't have to touch threads or mutexes at all.  I also implemented a version that spawned thousands of actors and that worked fine too although it was significantly slower for this implementation.

The only downsides I've found are that it doesn't work for interprocess/intermachine/distributed applications, and it's currently a little Windows-centric (although I got it working on a Mac and Linux machine without too much trouble).

I also tried libcppa and got a toy example working without too much trouble.  The API seems a little less stable and at the time documentation was scanty but I'm told it has been fleshed out more recently.

Comment: (While `Theron` itself only took a few hours to get working, building as a `mex` plugin from `Matlab` took significantly more work.  If anyone is interested in getting this working, see my blog posts here: http://absurdlycertain.blogspot.com/2011/09/preamble-what-follows-is-guide.html )

Comment: The state of libcppa's documentation has changed significantly. There is [a manual](http://neverlord.github.com/libcppa/manual/) as well as a [doxygen documentation](http://neverlord.github.com/libcppa/) and a [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/libcppa) to get additional support.

Comment: Thanks, I did get something working with libcppa pretty easily too.  I updated my answer to reflect this and your note about updated documentation.